# Sql server multi-instance drives and controllers

Tags: sql-server, disk-space, database-engine

I was wondering what is the best practice for drives and controllers when you are installing multiple Sql instances engines.

Are the similar pros and cons as in having different drives and controllers for data and log disk?

E.g having 10 instances engines residing on same D: disk with one controller or should you split them on different drives with own/shared controllers?

Comment: The best practice would be not to install 10 instances on the same server. This is kind of an XY question.

Comment: In days of virtual drivers and virtual controllers it makes no sense to apply best practices of physical magnetic drives. Plus if you have multiple instances on the same server performance and following of best practices is least of your concern.

Comment: Virtual devices and paravirtual devices should have their documentation checked for their own limitations and setup.